# ¿ Como darle mi estilo al footer, con una imagen...?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola estoy tratando de dar el estilo a mi footer, de la imagen que muestro dando la sensación de realismo, como si la hierba creciera hacia arriba. He pensado en que diera impresión de movimiento como un git, no se si eso sera posible, con javascript o bootstrap.
O debo  poner una imagen o git de fondo. He buscado alguna pista de como dar esa apariencia, u otra parecida sin lograrlo.
¿ Alguna idea de como puedo conseguirlo ?
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
footer {
    background-color: #404040;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0 30px ;
 
}

footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
 font-size: 14px;
}

footer a.totop {
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
footer a.totop:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<title>document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#intro">Casa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about">Sobre mi</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#service">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#works">Trabajos</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contacto</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

                            <h2 >Hola</h2>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vis tale malis tacimates et, graece doctus omnesque ne est, deserunt pertinacia ne nam. Pro eu
                            simul affert referrentur, natum mutat erroribus te his
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Ne mundi fabulas corrumpit vim, nulla vivendum conceptam eu nam. Ius ex principes complectitur, ex quo duis suscipit. Ius
                            fastidii reprimique no. Sadipscing appellantur pri ad. Oratio moderatius definitiones cum ex,
                            mea ne brute vivendum percipitur.
                        </p>
                        <a href="#service" class="btn btn-skin btn-scroll">What we do</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="section-heading text-center">
        <h2 class="h-bold">hola</h2>

        <h5>Web Design</h5>

        <p>
            Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
        </p>


        <h5>Web Design</h5>

        <p>
            Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
        </p>


        <p>
            Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
        </p>

                        <h5>Graphic design</h5>
                   
                        <p>
                            Ad denique euripidis signiferumque vim, iusto admodum quo cu. No tritani neglegentur mediocritatem duo.
                        </p>
 

    </section>

    <footer>
        <a href="#">Adios</a> Email</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te refieres a un **GIF**, en vez de *GIT*, si entendí bien, solo debes agregarlo al footer como fondo solo usando CSS, así:

```
.pie_pagina
{
   background-image: url(pasto-animacion.gif);
   /*Estos estilos te los recomiendo*/
   background-position: center bottom; /*Para que la imagen aparezca desde abajo*/
   background-size: auto 100px; /*o las medidas que quieras darle a la imagen*/
   background-repeat: repeat-x; /*Para que solo se repita a los lados y no hacia arriba*/  
}
```

Ahora, un gif es algo pesado y sobretodo si es muy realista, te recomiendo que busques un compresor o un estilo más flat (de colores planos) porque pesa menos. También puede ser bueno que si lo vas a hacer tu mismo (el gif), lo hagas mejor usando sprites.

Te doy un ejemplo rápido, de como puedes hacerlo.  (Si la imagen tarda en cargar. ya sabes porque es)

```css
footer{
  background-image: 
    url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b6470ae4b022e9ea88408d/t/561d64c1e4b09810cb5dbbae/1444766985860/CROP-Grass.gif?format=2500w');
    background-position: 50% 25vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
    /*La siguiente medida es porque no encontre una imagen como la que quieres tu*/
    background-size: 50% auto;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    min-height: 50vh;
}




/*Esto lo puedes ignorar*/
*{
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
body{
min-height: 100vh;
display:flex;
align-items: flex-end;
}
footer{
width: 100%;
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
color: white;
font-family: verdana;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<footer>

MIRA MI GIF DE HIERBAS

</footer>
```

Comment: Gracias @Edgar Gutiérrez la verdad es que esta muy bien. Puede valer. Quería saber si en vez de eso, que el borde superior del footer fuera irregular, simulando la hierba como en la imagen de muestra, que no fuera recto. Quizá lié un poco la cosa con lo del "Git" , Gif es el caso. Gracias.

Comment: Estuve probando, si no me dan alguna otra idea, daré tu respuesta por valida @Edgar Gutiérrez .Una cosa, ¿habría forma de reducir el gif del footer de la parte inferior..?? Gracias

Comment: Claro que puede reducirse, recuerda que te mencione esta propiedad: `background-size: auto 100px;*/` yo en mi demo use `100% auto`, pero puedes usar la medida que mejor se acomode por ejemplo `3em 10em` o `cover` que lo que hace es que el fondo sin importar el tamaño siempre ocupará el 100% de todo el contenedor.

Comment: Por cierto, ya encontraste el GIF como lo necesitabas? Porque ya con la imagen podría cuadrar mejor como quedaría.

Comment: No encontré uno que disimule con la parte anterior del footer.  El problema de la imagen es el mismo, la vi en otra web y tiene sus títulos y no lo puedo aprovechar. Mi idea era que pareciera que la hierba sube encima de la parte anterior del footer. Seguiré buscando. Gracias @Edgar Gutiérrez.

Comment: Pero añade la imagen o la url de como quieres imitar el efecto, estoy pensando quizás en una solución svg, pero no estoy seguro si es como quieres.

Comment: Vale, ya buscare una ideal. Otra cosa, que medida debo usar para recortar el footer de la parte inferior..? He probado a recortar el gif y no puedo.

Comment: A que te refieres con recortar el footer? Si es por la imagen recuerda que existe la propiedad `background-position: ` basta con que le pongas que empieza desde arriba, así: `top center` o que le pongas en el tamaño, que cubra la totalidad del alto `background-size: 100% 100%;` o que sobrepase el alto `background-size: 100% 150%;`, igual no entiendo mucho a que te refieres, puedes poner una imagen?

Comment: Perdona, quiero hacerle la mitad de alto, pero una vez lo he conseguido, ya no se como, pero me quitaba la parte de arriba del gif, y yo queria hacerle la mitad de alto, pero recortando el gif de la parte de abajo. Gracias.

Comment: Para que quede a la mitad del alto, sería: `background-size: auto 50%` y para que recorte la parte de abajo sería: `background-position: 50% 50%;`

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta para que veas como hago lo que quieres hacer. Advierto que muchas veces los porcentajes de **background-position**, no son dependientes del contenedor, por lo que muchas veces va a ser mejor usar medidas exactas o relativas al viewport (como yo que usé 25vh), solo debes recordar que el primer valor es **el eje X** y el segundo **el eje Y**, por lo que si quieres que empiece a 200px desde arriba, recortando abajo, tendrías que colocar: `background-position: 50% 200px`.

Comment: Gracias, al final se deforma, lo dejo como estaba con `background-position: center bottom; background-size: 100% auto;` Y no te molesto mas pues la cosa es que seria hacer mas el footer pero viendo la parte de arriba de las hierbas moviéndose . Tal y como estaba al principio, y cortar la pantalla de abajo, dejando el footer mas reducido, pero con la parte de git que mostraste la primera vez. No te preocupes, ya esta haciéndose esto muy extenso, Gracias por tu interés.